# MongoDB epoch timestamp to date

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I have an issue about mongodb projection, we are using mongodb v3.4 and documents have timestamp not date just timestamp as Integer.

Is there any way to change this timestamp to date while doing projection, except upgrading the mongodb's version?

EDIT:

In addition, we want to use spring data (org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate) for this operation. In native mongo shell we can make it such a command `new Date($timestamp)`, but by using spring aggregation functionalities it does not work.

Our example is below, we want to get month number from timestamp but we can not make it, we have tried three different ways but did not work.

```java
Aggregation.project()
     .andExpression("month({$add: [new Date(\"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z\"),$timestamp]})").as("monthInt")
     .andExpression("new Date(convert$timestamp)").as("dateStr")
     .andExpression("convert(input: NumberLong(\"$timestamp\"), to: \"date\")").as("dateStr")
```

Thanks for your attention and suggestion.

Comment: What kind of "timestamp as Integer"? In case it is the standard MongoDB/Javascript timestamp then simply `new Date(<timestamp>)` or `{$convert: { input: <timestamp>, to: "date"}}` See [Converting to a Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/index.html#convert-to-date)

Comment: Update  to a more recent MongoDB version then use $convert as specified in the previous comment.